# Apple magic mouse battery indicator on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: mouse, indicator, battery, apple

does anyone know how to display battery indicator in top panel for Apple magic mouse, on desktop computer,
when i type in shell 'upower -d' i get info about device, battery and percentage,
also if i go to system->power i can see wireless mouse and battery level,
but i just want simple percentage in top right corner

anyway to get this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 17.10 or above, there is a magic mouse battery indicator in Settings > Power > Devices.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See https://askubuntu.com/a/501024/67335.

My thinking is if you can write a shell script which gives you the information you want, then run indicator-sysmonitor and have it call your script.

Comment: I have added background script functionality to https://askubuntu.com/a/786708/67335 which would allow you to call a script/command of your choosing to parse the result of 'upower -d' and display in the panel.