# Ubuntu 14.04 Indicator Applet for remaining HDD space?

Tags: hard-drive, indicator

I've looked all over google but have yet to find what i'm looking for.
I just want a simple Indicator that shows the remaining HDD space for my drives.
Doesn't need to be fancy because it's being used on my laptop and i only have 1 HDD.

Answer (score 1):

Install indicator-sysmonitor from [Is an Internet connectivity indicator applet available for the Unity panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100306/is-an-internet-connectivity-indicator-applet-available-for-the-unity-panel/453975#453975).

You'll need to create a script that will contain a call to `df` or something similar and then parse out the required information.  Get the script going in the terminal first to ensure you have the correct value before adding it to the indicator.

Comment: I spoke too soon: there is a built-in free space sensor in this indicator...so up to you how you easy you want to make your life!

Comment: I have added background script functionality to https://askubuntu.com/a/786708/67335 which would allow you to call 'df' and display the result in the panel.